# Getting a MODULE_NOT_FOUND on NextJS project with a capacitor stripe import

Tags: webpack, next.js, capacitor

I have a nextJS project with capacitor and I need to use stripe. It uses a provider setup with React and I have to import it on my _app.js. In my next.config.js I have a fallback, but it doesn't seem to be working. It still gives me a MODULE_NOT_FOUND

```
config.resolve.fallback = {
            fs: false,
            module: false,
            "@capacitor-community/stripe": false
        }
```